# VLC 2.2.6 doesn't open

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, vlc

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and recently I upgraded my VLC from 2.2.2 to 2.2.6. But after that the GUI of VLC doesn't open. It just flashes in the taskbar and closes. There is no background task running as VLC. I tried reinstalling VLC but nothing happens. I tried launchin by command line which works good.

Comment: If you installed software from outside the Ubuntu repositories and it doesn't work you should report a bug to the devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You signed up for Ask Ubuntu today and this is your first question on Ask Ubuntu, so maybe you don't know that VLC 2.26 is an Ubuntu snap package. In order to install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install snapd  
sudo snap install vlc
```

Comment: thanks it worked. what is difference between apt and snap?

Comment: An apt package is a classic old school package that can be installed with the apt package manager using a command of the form: `sudo apt install <package-name>`. A snap package is a standalone package that can often be installed without installing any dependency packages along with it (like programs are installed in Windows) using a command of the form: `sudo snap install <snap-package-name>`. For this reason a snap package is usually a lot larger than the apt version of the same package.